# How can I get Debian 10 ssh to recognize my keypair?

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh, vps, debian-buster

I have a new Debian VPS, and I am able to access it but need to give my password on entering. After some simplification, I have ~/.ssh/id_rsa and ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub on my computer, with the server having ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub. This began with the new VPS, and several permutations haven't worked.

What do I need to connect to have key-based, passwordless ssh access to my server?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to copy the contents of `id_rsa.pub` into `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file in your server. Like this

```
cat id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

make sure the private key in your computer is not writable

```
chmod 400 id_rsa
```

then, ssh into the server using your private key

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa username@serverhostname
```

if you want to disable password based ssh login, you will have to modify the config file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file, and make sure `PasswordAuthentication no` is uncommented.

Comment: Hmm, tried again. I had already copied a public key to ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub on my computer, and added it to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys on the remote host. I ran through this recipe again, and I'm still prompted for a password.

Comment: Did you add a password for you ssh keys when creating them?